# How to handle bug fixes in Trunk Based Development?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

- Let’s say I have only one main branch and I successfully released sprint 1 to the production.
- Now I’m working on sprint 2 which spans 4 weeks, during this span, I have committed several user stories to the main branch and on to the QA for demo.
- Now, I have an urgent bug from the original sprint 1 release, but how do I fix that bug without including the sprint 2 user stories in the main branch? The main trunk already has many sprint 2 user stories.
- How do I apply the fix to the original sprint 1 release and then release to production? There is no production branch for me to branch off for the fix. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you have four week sprints and separate QA, I doubt trunk based development will work well for you; it's more for a CI/CD world.

Comment: You can branch off from the commit that went into production (was released) at any later time as needed (and one may even argue you should not do it before that point) creating a release branch to accept such fixes and backport into that.

Comment: Are you using Git or TFVC? Are you using TFS or Azure DevOps?

Comment: I'm using TFVC in TFS for now.

Comment: jon, I would like still to deploy CI/CD to QA.How come it won't be possible?

Answer (score -1):

Since you only have one branch, you may try to find the changeset that release to sprint 1, and branch from this changeset to fix the bug.

[image]

Comment: You're assuming the use of TFVC when the question has given no indication as to whether TFVC or Git is in use.

Comment: This is interesting. I didn't know you can create one changeset of the whole project. All this time we have multiple commits or change sets of multiple files. Is change set similar to label?

Comment: @shehz81 When you check in your changes, they are stored on the server as a changeset. Changesets contain the history of each item in version control. Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/find-view-changesets?view=azure-devops.